# TIdHTTPServer connection aborted

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I have a http server application and I'm using TIdHTTPServer.

The problem I'm facing is that whenever a client is making a request(via a web browser) and the client refreshes/closes the page before the entire data is sent, the connection is aborted, now the server raises an exception, is there a way to catch and log this and also stop the exception message from showing?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Are you running the server in or outside the debugger?

Comment: I'm running it within the IDE, the testing version runs on another machine without debugging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception that is thrown will only display a message box whilst running in the IDE.

The TIdHTTPServer will catch the exception itself and handle it. It doesn't cause a problem. If you feel the need, you can log these exceptions use the IdHTTPServer.OnException event, otherwise they're essentially discarded.

Comment: thank you, you are right! can't remember why on Earth I haven't thought of that, the exception gets caught in my try-except, but it's shown under the debugger...

Comment: The debugger is supposed to show exceptions. If you don't want it to show the one you are seeing, you can add the exception's class type to the debugger's list of exceptions to ignore. Also, do make sure that if you are using a `try..except` that you re-raise any `EIdException` derived exceptions that you catch, let the server handle them for you.

Comment: Thank you Remy, I forgot about this... haven't been working in Delphi for quite some time now...